# Can we associate business hours with workflow rules

Tags: workflow, case, email-alert, time-dependent-workflow, business-logic

we are currently working on the case object using custom case escalation workflows with email alerts that works based on the time dependant workflows.Even though we setup the business hours in the company information, the escalation mails are not working according to the business hours and holidays.Please help us with solution and links if any.

Comment: Workflow rules don't abide business hours, u can take a look at this idea,https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000Bpq3AAC. Also, take a look at this for alternatives,https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000gtCUAAY

Answer (score 1):

From App Setup | Customize | Cases | Escalation Rules you can define an escalation rule, and specify rule entries which should be evaluated in order until one matches. You can then specify further criteria with restrictions on business hours.

In our setup, the first entry specifies "Use business hours specified on case", and for how escalation times are set we use "Based on when the case is created" because the rule is related to a new case not getting a response within 1 working hour. The escalation action is then set to escalate after 1 hour and 0 minutes, and this does respect the business hours settings we have in place.